# Polar plot: label and legend rotation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using the polar library with pgfplots to plot a graph like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
   \usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]
\begin{polaraxis}
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (45,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(180,0.5) (172,1) (160,1)};
\legend{test}
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible that the 0 degree 'label' begins in the north and not in the east?
2. How can I rotate the legend?

Comment: Can you please expand your code snippet to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?  It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

Comment: \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]
\begin{polaraxis}
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (45,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(180,0.5) (172,1) (160,1)};
\legend {test}
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Comment: Thanks, but instead of making it a comment, just edit your question.  Have a look at the [about page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) and our [welcome page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for new users.

Answer (score 1):

The `rotate=90` key seems to work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]
\begin{polaraxis}[rotate=90]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (45,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(180,0.5) (172,1) (160,1)};
\legend{test}
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

For rotation of the legend: Christian (the package author/maintainer) wrote on [gmane.comp.tex.pgfplots a while back](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.pgfplots/10):

> the legend is typeset as pgf matrix for which [the pgf manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) says
>
> > Rotations and scaling have no eﬀect on a matrix as a whole (however, 
> >     you can still transform the contents of the cells normally). Before
> >     the  matrix is typeset, the rotational and scaling part of the
> >     transformation  matrix is reset."
>
> It seems the rotation of the matrix is not possible.

The post is old but the pgf manual still has this passage (Section 17.2 of the v2.10 manual).  So it's probably still not possible.

Comment: Hey Matthew, thank you for your fast help. It looks good but the x and y label don't look very nice now...

Comment: Label placement is very customizable.  Take a look at Section 4.14 of the pgfplots manual.

Comment: For the label placement you can also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116856/17151.