# Polar Plot x and y ticks and units

Tags: pgfplots, units

I'm having some trouble with polar plots. I generate the plot coordinates using Scilab and then plot them in Latex. I can't figure out how to remove the points (`mark = \empty` does nothing, but changing the mark with `mark=x` for example does nothing either), nor can I move the ticks out of the picture. Can anyone help please?

I want to add units to the ticks as well, degrees for the x ticks and dB for the y ticks.

My code is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[xmin=-90,xmax=90,rotate=90]
    \addplot table [x index=0, y index=1,col sep = comma, data cs=polarrad,mark = \empty]{mydata05.csv};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Polar plot]

Comment: Would it be possible to include the contents of `mydata05.csv` in your question? And if it's too big, perhaps you could cut it down to just a few points?

Comment: In the meantime, try adding `no markers` as an option to your `{polaraxis}` environment. Or maybe `mark=none`, I'm not sure which is the right one.

Comment: Concerning the units: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116496/1537 which might be related

Comment: The rotation could be a missing feature in pgfplots' polar axis: the feature which computes cool positions automatically does not work well with `rotate=90`. Perhaps it is even a bug. In other words: fixing the tick labels in you case might be more involved than one wants it to be ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As John said, you can remove the points by using the key `no markers` in the `polaraxis` options (or in the `\addplot` options if you only want to remove the marks for a single plot).

For moving the tick marks out the axis, you can put the following code snippet in your preamble, which will make sure that the labels are placed properly regardless of the axis rotation (`\pgftransform@angle` is a key that is set whenever `rotate=<angle>` is called):

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgftransform@angle{0}
\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel style={
        inner xsep=1pt,
        ellipse,
        anchor=\tick-(180-\pgftransform@angle)
    },
    yticklabel style={
        anchor=\pgftransform@angle
    }
}
\makeatother
```

For the degree symbol, you can use the approach from your other question ([Polar plots, add degree symbol and hide the radius axis labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116487/polar-plots-add-degree-symbol-and-hide-the-radius-axis-labels)), as Christian mentioned.

[image]

(And the same axis with `rotate=35`)

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\makeatletter
\def\pgftransform@angle{0}
\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel style={
        inner xsep=1pt,
        ellipse,
        anchor=\tick-(180-\pgftransform@angle)
    },
    yticklabel style={
        anchor=\pgftransform@angle
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[xmin=-90,xmax=90,rotate=90,
    domain=-90:90,
    xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
    no markers]
    \addplot +[orange, thick, smooth] {cos(x)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```