# pgf tikz polaraxis: Alignment of labels after rotation

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, ticks

How can labels be nicely positioned in a polaraxis environment ranging from -90...+90 degree and having the data facing south? In ideal case, the yaxis (0...1.0) will be arranged vertically at the lefthand side centered. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
  rotate=-90,
  xmin=-90,
  xmax=90,
  xtick={-90,-60,-30,0,30,60,90}
  ]
\addplot coordinates {(-60,1) (10,0.8) (80,0.2)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting the labels for rotated polar axes is a feature that's currently missing from PGFPlots, but you can fix the labels relatively easily by putting the following code (taken from [Polar Plot x and y ticks and units](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116830/polar-plot-x-and-y-ticks-and-units)) into your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgftransform@angle{0}
\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel style={
        inner xsep=1pt,
        ellipse,
        anchor=\tick-(180-\pgftransform@angle)
    },
    yticklabel style={
        anchor=\pgftransform@angle
    }
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\makeatletter
\def\pgftransform@angle{0}
\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel style={
        inner xsep=1pt,
        ellipse,
        anchor=\tick-(180-\pgftransform@angle)
    },
    yticklabel style={
        anchor=\pgftransform@angle
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
  rotate=-90,
  xmin=-90,
  xmax=90,
  xtick={-90,-60,-30,0,30,60,90}
  ]
\addplot coordinates {(-60,1) (10,0.8) (80,0.2)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great!
But how can I place the radial ticks horizontally e.g. {1, 0.5, 0, 0.5 1} or vertically {0, 0.5, 1} left/right of center?