# Polaraxis nonaligned negative yticklabel

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

I would like to plot a polar plot in dB scaling, in this case I have positive and negative values. Usually a negative radius is plotted in the opposite direction, but with the help of [transforming the coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267938/) I get the result I want.

But now there exists the problem that the negative and positive ticks are not perfectly aligned. I tried [a hint](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116830) but this only corrects the offset a bit. This could be due to the fact that the solution was given for a rotating ticks problem.

How can I get the radius axis ticks correctly aligned?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[%
      xtick={0,30,...,180},
      ymin=-25,
      ymax=10,
      xmax=180,
      y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+25},
      y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-25},
      xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
      yticklabel style={yshift=-0.5cm},
    ],
    \addplot[%
    ]
    coordinates{%
      (0,-15)
      (30,-5)
      (90,0)
      (120,5)
    };
  \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you think is misaligned. I think you mean that the negative `yticklabels` are a bit shifted to the right, right? But in fact the nodes *are* perfectly centered when you take the minus sign into account. To show that, you can add `draw=red` to the `yticklabel style` options. (And I recommend using `anchor=near yticklabel opposite` instead of `yshift`.)

Comment: Did my tip help you or do you need further assistance?

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to use `anchor=below` which is not allowed. An `anchor=north` also seems to yield the same result. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned [in the comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339228/polaraxis-nonaligned-negative-yticklabel?noredirect=1#comment832405_339228), the tick labels *are* perfectly aligned. Have a look at the comments in the code for more details.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{polaraxis}[
            ymin=-25,
            ymax=10,
            xmax=180,
            % when you have at PGFPlots v1.13 you can use the `xtick distance' feature
%            xtick={0,30,...,180},
            xtick distance=30,
            y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+25},
            y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-25},
            xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
            yticklabel style={
                % draw a frame around the tick labels to see, that they are
                % indeed centered
                draw=red,
                % (and use there is a better way to position the tick labels
                % on the other side of the axis ...)
%                yshift=-0.5cm,
                anchor=near yticklabel opposite,
            },
        ],
            \addplot coordinates {
                (0,-15) (30,-5) (90,0) (120,5)
            };
        \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]